# How do i draw on telnet interface using ncurses ..?

Tags: ruby, screen-scraping, telnet, ncurses

I am writing a small mud in ruby where i need some text box and menu items (TUI). The client connect to this application through telnet, i tried using NCurses but cant figure out how it can draw to a to a IO which is a socket ... is there any possible way i could develop my own text-box and menu widgets, i have tried looking at VT-100 ansi terminal escape codes. Could write some colored text thats it ... is it even possible to make event driven interfaces with standard telnet application.

Answer (score 2):

It would be easier to write a regular ncurses program / ruby script and the pipe it to a socket.

eg. hosting vi on a port

open a terminal and execute these as root

```
mkfifo ncpipe

nc -l -p 800 0<ncpipe |  vi   1>ncpipe
```

this hosts vi application on port 800
open another terminal

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 800
```

You can replace vi with your ncurses program.

Note: this is very basic example because nc handles only one incoming connection and then terminates. You will need other server program like "socat"

Comment: Surely this would only work with a single connection, though?

Comment: @Textmode well he's just using it as an example to show that curses applications can be forwarded. One could write a second server application that serves a new instance to each user

Answer (score 1):

NCurses does not understand how to write to IO::Socket as it is designed to write to STDOUT so only remaining way is ANSI escape codes also requesting switching telnet from line-mode to character mode on will using ANSI and VT-100 Escape codes would help in developing the textbox widget etc ....

http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences-vt-100.php # For color

http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/np.html#TELNET #for other modifications.